# Differentiate the expression

Tags: derivatives

i HAVE this expression that includes gamma functions.

Differentiate the following w.r.t. 't' then taking t=0 .

[image: gif]

Any hints are welcome, because I am clueless, at present how to solve it.

Comment: $$\Gamma'(t)=\Gamma(t)\Psi(t)$$?